# Where was the Torah that Moshe wrote kept?

Tags: moshe-rabbeinu, sefer-torah, mishkan-tabernacle

Did Moshe have a written copy of the Torah? If so, where was it kept when Moshe was alive? In the Mishkan (Tabernacle)? In the Kodesh haKodashim (Holy of Holies)?

Comment: See bava batra 14

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Devarim 31:24-26](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Deuteronomy.31.26?ven=The_Contemporary_Torah,_Jewish_Publication_Society,_2006&vhe=Miqra_according_to_the_Masorah&lang=bi&aliyot=0) describes Moshe writing a Torah scroll near his death and telling the Levites to place it next to the Holy Ark.

As @DoubleAA wrote in the comments, Rabbi Meir in [Bava Batra 14](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Bava_Batra.14a.10-11?ven=William_Davidson_Edition_-_English&vhe=William_Davidson_Edition_-_Vocalized_Aramaic&lang=bi) explained that this scroll was still kept in the Ark in later generations:

> "What biblical source indicates that a Torah scroll was placed there? As it is stated: “There was nothing in the Ark except the two tablets of stone which Moses put there” (I Kings 8:9). What does “there was nothing in the Ark except” mean? This is an example of a restriction following a restriction, as both terms, “nothing” and “except,” indicate that the Ark was empty. And there is a hermeneutical principle that a restriction following a restriction serves only to amplify and include other matters. In this case, it serves to include a Torah scroll that lies in the Ark. The baraita continues: With this explanation you have accounted for the entire length of the Ark; go now and account for the width of the Ark, which was nine handbreadths. How much space did the tablets occupy of the width of the Ark, which was nine handbreadths wide? Six handbreadths; therefore, three handbreadths were left there along the width of the Ark. Deduct a handbreadth from them: One-half a handbreadth for the thickness of this wall and one-half a handbreadth for the thickness of the other wall. Accordingly, two handbreadths were left there. What was their purpose? These were necessary so that the Torah scroll would be able to go in and out without being pressed; this is the statement of Rabbi Meir."

And so wrote the [Malbim on Melachim 2:22:8](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Malbim_on_II_Kings.22.8.1?vhe=On_Your_Way&lang=he&with=all&lang2=he).

There's also a midrash that Moshe wrote 12 more scrolls before he died and gave each one to each of the tribes, but I am unable to find the midrash right now.

Comment: "_There's also a midrash that Moshe wrote 12 more scrolls before he died and gave each one to each of the tribes, but I am unable to find the midrash right now_".  Ramabm says this [in the intro to Mishneh Torah](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Mishneh_Torah%2C_Transmission_of_the_Oral_Law.2?lang=bi&with=Commentary&lang2=en). Commentaries there cite [Devarim Rabbah on va-Yelekh (9:9)](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Devarim_Rabbah.9.9?lang=bi&lang2=en).

Comment: You need to clarify better who holds in the ark and who holds next to the ark.